# Android VideoView Http Live Streaming Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, android-videoview

I'm trying to create an application that can stream from Http Live Streaming (HLS) source.

So far, it is working as expected. However, I'm experiencing a problem with memory leaking issue.

As of this point, I'm losing roughly 6MB/hour while the VideoView is streaming from HLS server.

Currently, I must set VideoView = null and reinitialize the VideoView to get my memory back. However, that means there's a interruption on Live Streaming.

Is there any better way to clear the memory of VideoView without interrupting the video?

Any suggestions and feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: Put Log with AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: There's no error appeared in the log file at all until it is too late when it run out of memory. What I've done is make the activity show the current available memory on the screen and update them once per second. This is how I found out about the memory leak.

Comment: Could you post the relevant android code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of working on my project. I'd like to leave a conclusion on this post for whoever is encountering the same problem in the future.

**Conclusion**

This problem is caused by the video player software that's built by the manufacturer of the CPU/GPU. With exactly the same code, I run it on Amlogic board, I can see memory leak. However, if I run it on Qualcomm or Rockchip board, there's no memory leak problem.

With the later generation of Amlogic firmware update, this problem seems to go away.

Therefore, the primary cause of this problem is with the manufacturer's firmware code that handles hardware decoding for video.

So, if you encounter this problem, talk to the chip developer see if they have a patch to fix the memory leak problem.